# How to fix Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null error when using SeatsioClient in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, laravel-9

I am using the seats.io PHP client library to create and manage charts and events. I have installed the library using composer and I have created a SeatsioClient object with my region and secret key.

```
$seatsio= new SeatsioClient(Region::EU(), <WORKSPACE SECRET KEY>);
```

However, when I try to call any method on the SeatsioClient object, such as `$seatsio->charts->create()`, I get this error:

`Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null`

I have checked the seats.io API documentation and I don't see any problem with my request parameters. I have also checked the seats.io status page and the API seems to be working fine. My PHP version is 8.2 and I have enabled the curl extension.

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

References:

- https://docs.seats.io/docs/api/authentication/#examples
- https://github.com/seatsio/seatsio-php

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Go3.png)

Comment: Please post all relevant code and explain in detail when and where the error occurs. We're unable to help you find issues in your code unless you show it to us.

Comment: The full and exact error code with a stack trace would also be helpful